# How does swapInterval work in GFLW (and v-sync in general)?

Tags: lwjgl, vsync

When using v-sync, I'm wondering what something like GFLW does when a bufferswap is called when a screen update hasn't been completed at the time of the swap call.

Is the process stopped at that point, or is the bufferswap just ignored and the rest of the code is allowed to continue from that point?

Answer (score 0):

Usually OpenGL commands aren't exactly executed one by one as soon as the code flow reaches them. Normally they get queued and executed in batches.

So imagine the buffer swapping like a sort "I'm done; you can swap when ready" event on the driver command queue.

An interesting [thread](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/199389-understanding-the-opengl-main-loop-swapbuffers) about it